# Executing a string in python using system.check_call

Tags: python, os.system

I'm a novice at Python programming.

When I needed to execute some command-line commands inside a python script, I used to use `subprocess.check_call`, since I heard that this is better than `os.system` in several respects.

For example, when I need to execute the following command:

```
command = "display_info --name=tat"
```

I used the following command:

```
subprocess.check_call(command.split())
```

However, I found such kinds of usage of `split()`, which worked fine in the above case, don't work for the following cases.

```
 command = "process --subprocess_command=\"sox -t .sph in_file -t .wav outfile\""
```

I think the reason is because the segment enclosed between `\"` and `\"` shouldn't be split, although i'm not very sure..

in this case, what would be the right approach to execute this command using subprocess.check_call?

Answer (score 1):

As the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) suggests , use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) for spliting the command -

> shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args, especially in complex cases.

In your case it results in -

```
>>> import shlex
>>> command = "process --subprocess_command=\"sox -t .sph in_file -t .wav outfile\""
>>> shlex.split(command)
['process', '--subprocess_command=sox -t .sph in_file -t .wav outfile']
```